# Python typing: Narrowing type from function that returns a Union

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I have difficulties finding **return types** that satisfy `mypy`. I have two functions. The first one returns a `Union` type, since the type depends on the parameter given to the function. The second function calls the first one with a default parameter. Thus, the type is not a `Union` type -- it can be narrowed down to one of the types in the `Union`.

Let me give you an example of a very simple version of my problem:

```py
from typing import Union


def first(as_string: bool) -> Union[str, int]:
    if as_string:
        return "42"
    else:
        return 42


def second(as_string: bool) -> str:
    return first(True)
```

This causes an error:

```py
Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "Union[str, int]")
```

How can I prevent `mypy` from throwing an error while still using type hints?

If you want to suggest splitting the first function, please take in mind that this is just a simplification. My (first) function receives a function (`sklearn.metrics` function) and will return a scalar most of the time. Only when applying a confusion matrix, the type changes. The first function does some preprocessing and than applies the metric. I simply want to have a differently named function for the confusion matrix since I think it is a special case of a metric.

Comment: What's the type of `as_string`? `bool`?

Comment: Yes. But this is not causing me any trouble. It is just the return type, that is a problem.

Comment: Got it, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Python 3.10 added the [`typing.TypeGuard`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard) annotation for _type narrowing_, and [it's supported by mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Comment: @NunoAndré I'll add here again that `TypeGuard` seems to me like a hacky solution that encourages bad design. Maybe it has its uses, but I suspect that 99% of the time, it's not the right solution

Comment: Thank you for showing TypeGuard. It does not look like it solves my problem. The suggest cast solution below seems to be more handy for me. Thank you for the hint though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mypy` can't infer the relationship between the types of the parameters and the types of the return values.

You have two options:

1. Use an `assert` to make sure that the type is correct:

   ```py
   def second(as_string) -> str:
       ret = first(True)
       assert isinstance(ret, str)
       return ret
   ```
2. You can use `typing.cast` to assert to the typechecker without altering runtime behavior (i.e. without introducing the potential for an `AssertionError` to be raised).

   ```py
   from typing import cast

   def second(as_string) -> str:
       return cast(str, first(True))
   ```