# How to receive the return value when the type hint is Union[Awaitable[int], int]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, pylance, redis-py

My python code is using [redis-py](https://github.com/redis/redis-py) to query redis. I noticed the return value type hint of redis-py functions are always like: Union[Awaitable[int], int]: (e.g. [redis.commands.core.py:L4824](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/master/redis/commands/core.py#L4824))

```
    def hlen(self, name: str) -> Union[Awaitable[int], int]:
    """
    Return the number of elements in hash ``name``

    For more information see https://redis.io/commands/hlen
    """
    return self.execute_command("HLEN", name)
```

When I receive the value as normal

```
dict_size = redis.hlen("dict_key")
assert dict_size < 10
```

Pylance will remind me

```
Operator "<=" not supported for types "Awaitable[int] | int" and "Literal[10]"
  Operator "<=" not supported for types "Awaitable[int]" and "Literal[10]"
```

How to let Pylance know I am not calling the function in asynchronous way, so I can mitigate this type checking error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python typing: Narrowing type from function that returns a Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845596/python-typing-narrowing-type-from-function-that-returns-a-union)

Comment: (above question is for mypy, but the solution is the same)

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you! That helps, and I am planning to use `cast()` for now. Let's see if there's a better solution